# ssl exception to display insecure content

Tags: .htaccess, exception, ssl, https

I´m forcing ssl in my site using:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

but im using an ad newtork that doesn´t have SSL enabled.
it is possible to displat that content without the alert of insecure content to the users?
maybe with an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you'll have any luck with that. The ad network needs to provide `SSL` code. The browser/client tells you that you are displaying insecure content and htaccess won't be able to hide that.

Even *Google Adsense* does not have `SSL` support. Internet explorer is typically the browser that gives the intrusive dialog warning versus other browsers show the error in the console. There are ad networks that do offer SSL though.

In Chrome, if the `https` connection is broken it shows it in the address bar crossed out in red. I personally don't want users to see that and think my site is not secure in certain areas just because of some ads.

I don't encrypt my whole site because I don't feel it's necessary. It seems to be a fad these days but I feel it's overkill and unnecessary most of the time. I only use `SSL` on important pages such as login pages, account settings or any type of payment area. Otherwise the whole site doesn't need it and will prevent users from seeing the insecure content warning. If you're whole site is not one big site of sensitive content and probably isn't sense it most likely public, maybe it's not necessary to force `https` on your entire site. Just a suggestion to get around the warning message.

**Updated**:

Try this code in regards to your comment.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (signup|settings)
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: you are right.. i will only secure signup and settings. but i need to do the opposite on all the other pages `#RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(signup|settings) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]` this is what i have so far. thank you

Comment: @handsome see updated answer and see if that works for you instead of the one you're using.

Comment: SSL is not just a fad (anymore) http://searchengineland.com/google-starts-giving-ranking-boost-secure-httpsssl-sites-199446